# Ho wo remove press any key to continue in this code

Tags: batch-file

I have a script in batch file.

```
    @echo off
    call :routine today -1

    echo %%day%% is set to "%day%" (without the quotes)
    echo %%YY%% is set to %YY%
    echo %%MM%% is set to %MM%
    echo %%DD%% is set to %DD%
    set day=%MM%/%DD%/%YY%
    echo %day%
     pause

     :routine
        setlocal
        set date1=%1
      set qty=%2
      set separator=%~3
     if /i "%date1%" EQU "TODAY" (set date1=now) else (set date1="%date1%")
     echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%qty%,%date1%)
     echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" d=weekday(s)
      echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^&_
    echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+month(s),2)^&_
    echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+day(s),2)^&_
     echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         d
     for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set result=%%a
    del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
    endlocal& (
   set "YY=%result:~0,4%"
   set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
  set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
   set "daynum=%result:~-1%"
  )
  set "day=%YY%%separator%%MM%%separator%%DD%"
```

This code executes fine but at the same time ask user to press any key, which i dont want.

Kindly help me out. any lead is appreciated

Comment: at what stage is it happening?

Comment: @user2310289 : i dont know exactly coz i have taken this code from net

Comment: Lucky it did not trash your computer then.  Understand scripts before running them.

Answer (score 3):

Change `pause` with `exit /b`.

You have defined a subroutine to generate a temporary vbsfile to operate with dates. It is supossed to be called with parameters, but when you remove the `pause` line, or when you press a key, the execution of code continues entering the subroutine but in this case, without parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have your "PAUSE" command after echo %day%
That will halt until key pressed.

Comment: if i remove the pause then i am getting this error :`C:\DOCUME~1\JYOTI~1.BHA\LOCALS~1\Temp\h.vbs(1, 2) Microsoft VBScript runtime err
or: Type mismatch: '[string: ""]'`

Answer (score 0):

Simple remove the `pause` keyword.

```
@echo off
call :routine today -1

echo %%day%% is set to "%day%" (without the quotes)
echo %%YY%% is set to %YY%
echo %%MM%% is set to %MM%
echo %%DD%% is set to %DD%
set day=%MM%/%DD%/%YY%
echo %day%


:routine
setlocal
set date1=%1
set qty=%2
set separator=%~3
if /i "%date1%" EQU "TODAY" (set date1=now) else (set date1="%date1%")
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%qty%,%date1%)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+month(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+day(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         d
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set result=%%a
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
endlocal& (
set "YY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "daynum=%result:~-1%"
)
set "day=%YY%%separator%%MM%%separator%%DD%"
```

And that should do what you want. Btw, if you have little understanding of batch, you should not run them on your computer as they can easily damage all of your stuff.

Mona